# How can I validate YAML with JSON schema

Tags: json, validation, go, yaml

Let's say I want to validate YAML and I convert it to JSON to use the JSON schema.

For example I've YAML like following:

```
    dep:
     name: ui
     path: ui
     requires:
       name: users
       properties:
       name: users
     name: ui2
     path: be
     requires:
       name: users1
```

What I want to validate is that the name of dep is unique which can be achieved like following

```
{
   "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
   "type":"object",
   "properties":{
      "name":{
         "type":"array",
         "items":{
            "type":"string",
            "pattern":"/^[A-Za-z0-9_-.]+$/"
         },
         "uniqueItems":true
      }
   },
   "required":[
      "name"
   ]
}
```

But what about the **line number** for example if user put `ui` instead `ui2` in the **second instance** of dep, how it should give you the line num?

Comment: this might help https://www.npmjs.com/package/pajv#validate-data

Comment: The indention of you YAML looks wrong.

Comment: @LutzHorn - yes, I've fixed it ...thanks